# TFS 2012 - "Found in" bug field and Gated Build

Tags: tfs

Is there any way of hiding gated builds so they do not get listed in the "Found in" bug field?

Also: The "Found in" field is ordered ascending. I am trying to find an way to have this field ordered descending and/or to be populated automatically by the last version available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael,

> Is there any way of hiding gated builds so they do not get listed in
>   the "Found in" bug field?

There is not, the "Found In" field will reflect the first build that is executed that contains the CheckIn that is both associated and "resolves" that bug. This is expected and documented behaviour.

**I would be interested in what you are trying to achieve that this is interfering with.**

> The "Found in" field is ordered ascending. I am trying to find an way
>   to have this field ordered descending and/or to be populated
>   automatically by the last version available.

There is no way to change the default order and it is based on a standard Alfa sort. The field is always populated automatically by the build script and should reflect all of the currently active builds in your Team Project. When you delete a build it will be removed from that list as well.

Comment: We never test gated builds and those builds only pollute the "found in" field, that is what I am try to achieve. Also, not sorting the field descending makes more difficult to find the last available build. To avoid polluting the field I must sometimes clean the global list what is a very boring job.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft Test Manager it will know what has been checked in regardless of what it said on the work item...

Comment: Isn't there some way to modify the template to allow a custom list of builds for the "found in" field?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971.aspx  I'm trying to solve a similar issue and found the link.  Will pass this along to my TFS admin to see if it's possible.